# SignalR / MVC Controller Actions not serialising DateTime the same

Tags: asp.net-mvc, signalr

I have a small game that's making use of SignalR, which pushes a stream of events to the client.

This event stream is also available as a `JsonResult` on a normal MVC controller action.

Both use the same events, but when serialised, the SignalR action is formats date as

`"2013-02-07T22:22:32.575"`

Where as the MVC action formats dates as

`"\/Date(1360171089406)\/"`

I'd like them to be a consistent format.

Why is there a mismatch? Are there any configuration/extensibility points in either pipeline to change how dates are formatted?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yep you can change it by tweaking the JsonSerializer.

```
var serializer = new JsonNetSerializer(new JsonSerializerSettings
{
    DateFormatHandling = DateFormatHandling.MicrosoftDateFormat
});

GlobalHost.DependencyResolver.Register(typeof(IJsonSerializer), () => serializer);
```

Put that in Global.asax before calling MapHubs.

Comment: Perfect, cheers. 

Also - you responded so quickly I can't actually mark this as the answer yet. Good work :)